# my Atlas page is blank

Tags: atlas

I am getting a bit worried that I may not have configured TOR correctly because my Atlas page is blank, the search window does not return anything. How is this feature suppose to work. I read around and it is suppose to contain a information on the exit nobes. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at Atlas page is:

1. Click [Test Tor Network Settings](https://check.torproject.org/?lang=en_US) from ***about:tor*** page.
2. Click [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/C5F6834D7C8DB8535E63751A1044D6D74BCF2A2D) at the middle of ***check.torproject.org*** page and make sure you allow script before initiation of step 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find any information about your relay at Atlas, the best guess is that your relay is not configured correct.

So check your log file first. It should not contain any error messages or warnings. In the case of a relay you should find a confirmation that your relay is reachable from the outside.

If the above log file seems correct to you, you can use [Exonerator](https://exonerator.torproject.org/) to find out if your server was registered as relay. Furthermore you can download another copy of Tor or Tor Browser Bundle and look for your IP address in the consensus information.